# Obtaining Consent with the User Messaging Platform Android

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to implement UE consent that lets the user select if he wants personalized ads in Android, using Admob. I'm doing this with "Funding choices", with the user messaging platform.

I followed this quick start guide:

https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start

To simplify, I selected only google in my providers lists.

The problem is, when I simulate a user from the ue, the form shows. But when I choose personalized or non-personalized, the consent status changes to OBTAINED, but the consent type remains in UNKNOWN.

I'm using this versions of admob and ump:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:1.0.0'
```

Comment: I am testing this too. The problem is also that if the user "declined" everything in the options then no ads will be shown anymore. Thats very bad in my opinion.I wrote a feedback to google.  I hope they will improve this soon. Also if you choose the layout with the option "decline" then no ads are served anymore. There should be an option to finish the app if the user declined everything so he cannot use the app anymore without ads

Comment: I have this issue as well, not sure what's going on but my guess is it's an SDK issue or something. Consenting and not consenting gives me the same results... Unknown

Comment: I finally used com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.8 and it works ok. I wasn't able to make the User Messaging Platform work.

Comment: Same issue for me too ! Any solution yet ?

Comment: Same issue. I was looking to update to their newer model of requesting Ad Consent, as the ads.consent library is listed as legacy. The only option I see is providing non personalized ads for now with this library, which doesn't seem reasonable. I guess this library isn't ready for primetime.

Comment: @takluiper does the old library still work?

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue, but a Google Engineer pointed me in the right direction.
Apparently this is the default behavior if you're using the IAB TCF v2 framework. The consent type is only applicable to the simplified version of the form. The full conversation can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/adops/comments/ifh6n9/anybody_using_google_funding_choices_for_gdpr_cmp/)
Since the Google documentation is lacking information I had to dig a little deeper to find the answer on the IAB Techlab Github.

To find the Consent status of your user all you need is [SharedPreferences(Android)](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) OR [NSUserDefaults(iOS)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults)
the key value pairs and full explanation can be found
[here](https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework/blob/master/TCFv2/IAB%20Tech%20Lab%20-%20CMP%20API%20v2.md#in-app-details)

So to solve your problem be sure to check out the [In-App Details](https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework/blob/master/TCFv2/IAB%20Tech%20Lab%20-%20CMP%20API%20v2.md#in-app-details) section:

1. An app publisher should embed a CMP SDK – The setup and
   configuration as well as the protocol for how to initialize the CMP
   SDK are all proprietary to each CMP SDK. (Google Funding Choices)
2. Since more than one CMP SDK may be included in publishers' linked
   SDKs, the publisher must initialize only one of them. The
   initialized CMP shall set IABTCF_CmpSdkID with its ID as soon as it
   is initialized in the app to signal to vendors that a CMP is
   present.
3. The CMP SDK will determine if GDPR applies to this user in this context.
   But, a publisher may choose to initialize a CMP dialogue UI
   manually.
4. The CMP shall set the NSUserDefaults(iOS) or
   SharedPreferences(Android) variables and vendors will then be able
   to read from them directly.
5. Vendors should listen to IABTCF_* key updates to retrieve new TC
   data from NSUserDefaults(iOS) or SharedPreferences(Android).

I hope this answers your question, but if your stuck somewhere please let me know!

Comment: Hi Alexander this still does not solve the problem to show at least "not personalizied" ads to the user. Because the submit button disables all ads. If IABTCF_PurposeConsents is = then the only chance is to reload the form again and again and again ...until the user agrees. Is is very annoying

Comment: Hi Frank, I think this is beyond the scope of the question, however I posted another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63464270/how-to-request-non-personalized-admob-ads-with-the-new-unified-messaging-platfor/64245927#64245927). But yes it is very annoying, without certain consents (especially cookies) Google won't be able to serve ads for now.. As to how they will resolve this who knows. Maybe it’s a new dawn in the world of mobile advertising..

Comment: the answer is not relevant to the question!

Comment: What about CCPA? Does Funding Choices provide an end-to-end solution for CCPA as well like it does for GDPR?

Answer (score 1):

For any flutter developers struggling with this...

After a week of getting absolutely nowhere with Google... their philosophy seems to be to turn AdMob into a dumpster fire on purpose... I have settled on my interim solution until they hopefully one day get their act together.

In short i am...

1. presenting the user the official google consent screen
2. using the iabtcf_consent_info package to retrieve their responses
3. Passing those responses through a custom parser class which translates their responses into the information we actually care about 'no ads, untargetted ads, targetted ads'
4. Outputting that summary via a stream
5. Disabling access to certain features if that stream is outputting 'no ads'

If the stream outputs 'no-ads', then i present a dialog to them when they reach the home page, explaining why certain features are disabled and inviting them to resubmit their consent options.

This is a dreadful user experience of course... entering a bunch of cryptic consent options only to be rebuffed at the home page and told to do it again because their chosen combination was wrong... But this seems to be the user experience Google want.

Either that or they're seriously expecting us to support the costs of non-consenting users without any means to monetise them!

The following is my parser class incase anyone would like to follow a similar approach.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:buck_the_critics/enums.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:iabtcf_consent_info/iabtcf_consent_info.dart';
class AdmobConsentParser {
  // User must consent to these for any ads at all
  List < DataUsagePurpose > consentsRequiredForAds = [
    DataUsagePurpose.storeAndAccessInformationOnADevice // 1
  ];
  // User must consent to these for targetted ads
  List < DataUsagePurpose > consentsRequiredForTargettedAds = [
    DataUsagePurpose.storeAndAccessInformationOnADevice, // 1
    DataUsagePurpose.createAPersonalisedAdsProfile, // 3
    DataUsagePurpose.selectPersonalisedAds, // 4
  ];
  // User must either consent or NOT untoggle legitimate interest for any of these for any ads at all
  List < DataUsagePurpose > usagesRequiringConsentOrLegitimateInterest = [
    DataUsagePurpose.selectBasicAds, // 2
    DataUsagePurpose.measureAdPerformance, // 7
    DataUsagePurpose.applyMarketResearchToGenerateAudienceInsights, // 9
    DataUsagePurpose.developAndImproveProducts // 10
  ];
  Future < AdConsent > getAdConsentLevel(BasicConsentInfo ? usersConsent) async {
    if (usersConsent != null && usersConsent is ConsentInfo) {
      final gdprApplies = isGDPR(usersConsent);
      if (gdprApplies == true) {
        final targetedAds = await canShowPersonalizedAds(usersConsent);
        if (targetedAds != null && targetedAds) {
          return AdConsent.targeted;
        } else {
          final untargetedAds = await canShowAds(usersConsent);
          if (untargetedAds != null && untargetedAds) {
            return AdConsent.untargeted;
          } else {
            return AdConsent.none;
          }
        }
      } else {
        return AdConsent.none;
      }
    } else {
      return AdConsent.targeted;
    }
  }
  bool ? isGDPR(BasicConsentInfo ? usersConsent) {
    return usersConsent ? .gdprApplies;
  }
  // https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework/blob/master/TCFv2/IAB%20Tech%20Lab%20-%20CMP%20API%20v2.md#in-app-details
  // https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9760862?hl=en&ref_topic=9756841
  Future < bool ? > canShowAds(ConsentInfo usersConsent) async {
    final hasConsent = _hasConsent(usersConsent, consentsRequiredForAds);
    final hasConsentOrLegitimateInterest = _hasConsentOrLegitimateInterest(
      usersConsent, usagesRequiringConsentOrLegitimateInterest);
    return hasConsent && hasConsentOrLegitimateInterest;
  }
  // https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework/blob/master/TCFv2/IAB%20Tech%20Lab%20-%20CMP%20API%20v2.md#in-app-details
  // https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9760862?hl=en&ref_topic=9756841
  Future < bool ? > canShowPersonalizedAds(ConsentInfo usersConsent) async {
    return _hasConsent(usersConsent, consentsRequiredForTargettedAds) &&
      _hasConsentOrLegitimateInterest(
        usersConsent, usagesRequiringConsentOrLegitimateInterest);
  }
  _hasConsent(
    ConsentInfo usersConsent, List < DataUsagePurpose > requiredConsents) {
    return requiredConsents
      .every((purpose) => usersConsent.purposeConsents.contains(purpose));
  }
  _hasConsentOrLegitimateInterest(ConsentInfo usersConsent,
    List < DataUsagePurpose > requiredLegitimateInterests) {
    return requiredLegitimateInterests.every((purpose) =>
      usersConsent.purposeConsents.contains(purpose) ||
      usersConsent.purposeLegitimateInterests.contains(purpose));
  }
}
final admobConsentParserProvider = Provider.autoDispose((ref) {
  return AdmobConsentParser();
});
final adConsentLevelProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose < AdConsent > ((ref) {
  final controller = StreamController < AdConsent > ();
  final consentParser = ref.watch(admobConsentParserProvider);
  IabtcfConsentInfo.instance.consentInfo().listen((event) async {
    final consentLevel = await consentParser.getAdConsentLevel(event);
    controller.sink.add(consentLevel);
  });
  return controller.stream;
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).