# Google UMP EU consent message: why should we choose the option including 'Do not consent'?

Tags: admob, gdprconsentform

The generation of an EU (GDPR) consent message in the UMP / FundingChoices backend is initiated with a selection for "Select the consent choices your users see" and it consists of two options, see screenshot:

[image]

The question is, **why would we choose the second option**? The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63464270/how-to-request-non-personalized-admob-ads-with-the-new-unified-messaging-platfor) suggests that if 'do not consent' is selected then no ads will load. But using the legacy Consent SDK, choosing the equivalent option allows ads (presumably non personalized) to load.

Are we therefore 'supposed' to choose the first option and let the user disable personalization within the 'Manage options' step?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about managing a business relationship, communicating between the question OP and a third party, and/or dealing with a legal issue. In other words, it's not about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic]. You might be able to get help from the Customer Service for the company you are interfacing with. If you want an interpretation of legal requirements, it might be appropriate to ask on [law.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second option is mostly useful for people that want to offer an alternative to consenting, eg.: Buying a subscription. You can tweak the text of the Google UMP, so you could change 'do not consent' to 'Buy Ad-Free' or something similar.

This becomes increasingly important if you decide to not allow the user to use the app if they manage their consent 'wrongly'. (eg.: No consent for purpose 1) You could force them to go back to the consent popup and make the 'right' decision, but then they don't really have a free choice to decline certain consents, at which point offering a paid alternative becomes important to stay compliant.

So yes, there is no reason to choose the second option 'in and of itself', but it can be useful if you use it to trigger specific flows or popups.