# Google Funding Choices: How can I check if the user gave consent for a specific vendor?

Tags: android, ios, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

As part of the "IAB Europe Transparency & Consent Framework" in Google's Funding Choices I can specify a list of vendors. Some of the vendors are tagged with "TCF" (see the image below). As I understand these vendors are obliged to read the data which is provided by Google's "User Messaging Platform". This post explains this: [Obtaining Consent with the User Messaging Platform Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63415275/obtaining-consent-with-the-user-messaging-platform-android). The Google framework must save the TCF data in UserDefaults/SharedPreferences, so the vendors can access the data to know if they are allowed to use user data or not (see: [here](https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework/blob/master/TCFv2/IAB%20Tech%20Lab%20-%20CMP%20API%20v2.md#in-app-details)).

My question is now: **How can I check the consent for vendors which are not part of the TCF?** For example Facebook or AppLovin. Google also notes that there is a custom handling required (https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/ios/quick-start#mediation). But I can not find a way on how to retrieve the information if the user gave consent for a specific vendor or not.

[image]

Here is my code on reading some values provided by Google's User Messaging Platform:

```
let gdprApplies = UserDefaultsService.userDefaults.bool(forKey: "IABTCF_gdprApplies")
let purposeOneTreatment = UserDefaultsService.userDefaults.bool(forKey: "IABTCF_PurposeOneTreatment")
let tcString = UserDefaultsService.userDefaults.string(forKey: "IABTCF_TCString")
let vendorConsents = UserDefaultsService.userDefaults.string(forKey: "IABTCF_VendorConsents")
let vendorLegitimateInterests = UserDefaultsService.userDefaults.string(forKey: "IABTCF_VendorLegitimateInterests")
let purposeConsents = UserDefaultsService.userDefaults.string(forKey: "IABTCF_PurposeConsents")
let purposeLegitimateInterests = UserDefaultsService.userDefaults.string(forKey: "IABTCF_PurposeLegitimateInterests")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve this data by key IABTCF_AddtlConsent

https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/9681920?hl=en